# Check for existing value inside of Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: The description of the node]

Hello, I have a problem I created a Registration form and im trying to check if there is any user which have a certain username inside the Firebase Db. I tried to get the reference of all the users.

```
var users = Database.database().reference("users")
```

But I don't know how I could check if there is any user with a specified username.

Comment: You can search on users & check if there exists the specified username by a single for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for that. Something like:

```
let query = users.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").equalTo("two")
```

Then [execute the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once) and check whether the [result snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#exists) exists.

---

Note though that you won't be able to guarantee uniqueness in this way. If multiple users perform the check at the same time, they may both end up claiming the same user name.

To guarantee a unique user name, you will need to store the user names as the key - as keys are by definition unique within their parent node. For more on this, see some of these top [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%20unique%20username) and possibly also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%20unique%20username%20user%3a209103).